# Aligning center div

Tags: html, css, center, centering

I built a bottom header with a toggle for a menu on the bottom. The toggle portion is not aligning with the `<span>` right next to it. It's almost exactly one line-height below for some reason.

**Code** - https://jsfiddle.net/odvd05d8/

I tried using margin but it moves the side divs as well. I also tried to clear whitespace as most of the elements are inline, but that didn't work either.

Any suggestions would be really helpful. Thank you sincerely.

Comment: Update: I also tried to clear all floats after, but that didn't work either

Comment: Not sure if I clearly understand. Do you want [Something like this?](https://jsfiddle.net/odvd05d8/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use as in css as may it's help you

```
.dropdown{
  top:-20px;
}
```